# React native scanning libraries

Tags: react-native, mobile, scanning

I am looking for react-native scanning libraries that provide features like cropping, a border on the UI, blur detection, edge detection out of the box. I did come across [Scanbot SDK](https://scanbot.io/) but I wanted to know if there is anything else in the market that I can compare with. I am looking to do something like what dropbox does with documents.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow!